# php dynamic double drop down menu

Tags: php, html, forms, dynamic, drop-down-menu

Currently I try to build two linked drop down menu from the same table..
This is the table :-

Table Name : items_sold

```
 no      |    category   |   item          |  model
-------------------------------------------------------------
1        |   stationery  |  pen            |  pilot
2        |   stationery  |  pencil         | stabilo
3        |   stationery  |  pen            |  stabilo
4        |   it stuff    |  pc             |  lenovo thinkcentre
5        |   it stuff    |  pc             |  asus
6        |   it stuff    |  notebook       |  acer aspire zero
```

for the first drop down menu i already created this :-

```
<select name=item>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT item FROM items_sold WHERE category='$category'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value"<?php echo $row['item']; ?>"><?php echo $row['item']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

And for the second drop down menu i try this code :-

```
<select name="model">
<?php
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM items_sold WHERE category='$category' AND item=$row['item']";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { ?>
<option value"<?php echo $row1['model']; ?>"><?php echo $row1['model']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

I try to show the model of the item based on what item the user has selected from the first menu. But nothing appear at the second drop down menu. Looks like something wrong here... Is there any way I can do this without using javascript?

TQ

Comment: Your statement on the second looks wrong: `$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM items_sold WHERE category='$category' AND item='".$row['item']."'";`

Comment: Thanks @Rasclatt for your reply. Already tried that, but it still not working. It seems like the second part can't read $row['item'] from the first loop..

Comment: Yeah, I think what you are trying to do is better served using Javascript. Is there a reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: So just to get you right, you want to be able to select "stationery" and have it load `pilot`,`stabilo`,`stabilo`?

Comment: select item=pc, and `lenovo thinkcentre` & `asus` will appear

Comment: Ok, yeah, so to do what you want, you can do it without javascript but it's a super pain in the @$$. You have to select the one dropdown, then submit the form, then on reload, it will read that setting and load the second dropdown.

Comment: How do you get `$row['item']` within second query..

Comment: @NarendraSisodia @Rasclatt that is the part that i want to learn more.. `$row['item']` can't be retrieve from the second query.. any way that i can pass that value? i think i don't have any option here.. have to use javascript.. anyone expert on this?

Comment: @Alieym http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_drop_down_list.php this might help you to learn dynamic dropdown

Comment: Hello @Rasclatt.. since u r talking about javascript and i'm not familiar with it, how to add javascript in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is wrong. Please make it as

```
<select name="model">
  <?php
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM items_sold WHERE category='$category' AND item=$row[item]";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { ?>
  <option value"<?=$row1['model']?>">
  <?=$row1['model'];?>
  </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```